# Webrtc static libraries on Android

Tags: android, webrtc

For the Android project I am working on, I need to use webrtc static libraries for ARM as well as x86.

Following the tutorial at http://andrii.sergiienko.me/?go=all/building-webrtc-demo-for-android/, I managed to build the demo application for Android on my Ubuntu box.

However, my main interest is in obtaining static libraries that I can use with my application. Searching for `'libwebrtc*a'` files, I see the following two files:

```
./src/out/Release/obj/webrtc/libwebrtc.a
./src/out/Release/obj/webrtc/libwebrtc_common.a
```

Are these the right webrtc static libraries? The file size seem to be too small. Also, how do I build for ARM as well as x86? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [script](https://github.com/sourcey/webrtc-builds) (still work, tested by me) in order to build a fat webrtc lib.

Then you have to add the .a (just libwebrtc.a from 'obj' directory after the build is ready) to your project.